# Trying to sniff http packets using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

The program runs fine when I am not trying to filter http links but it shows almost nothing when I use the code, I don't see any problem in the code and I have already used `pip install scapy_http`.

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http

def sniff(interface): 
   scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False , prn= process_sniffed_packet)

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
   if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
       print(packet)

sniff('eth0')
```

Blank screen until i press `ctrl+c`. It shows some weird links after around 20 seconds  but I am not on those pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine :)

1. Open Wireshark togrther with running your code, and filter on http request packets. When I did it- there were no packets that were seen on Wireshark and not catched by the code
2. I used Chrome to open web pages, and indeed didn't see many packets. In Wireshark I saw that the packets appear as TLS protocol instead. This is probably because of the way Chrome works or the use of HTTPS protocol.
3. To solve this- I opened Internet Explorer- tons of HTTP packets appeared right away- both in Wireshark and in your code.
4. Use `packet.show()` instead of `print packet`- it will be easier to investigate what you see